# How to extract QR code scan results from ActivityResultLauncher

Tags: java, android, scanf

I'm using ZXing API and using ActivityResultLauncher to launch the camera to scan a QR code and try to extract the QR code data. As onActivityResult is deprecated I need to use ActivityResultLauncher. But result.getData(); giving me the following:[image: result.getData() responce]

I have the following code:`

```
activityResultLaucher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                if(result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK && result.getData() != null){
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result.getData().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

and: `

```
IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
String ScanPromptMessage=App.getTranslationString(this, R.string.ScanPrompt);
scanIntegrator.setPrompt(ScanPromptMessage);
activityResultLaucher.launch(scanIntegrator.createScanIntent());
```

``
This code lauches scanner and scans successfully but not been able to extract the QR code data. How can I extract the QR code data? Could you please help?

Comment: You have to use the ScanResult class on your result.

Comment: @blackapps thanks. Could you please share some example codes?

Comment: I havent. I just then googled and immediately hit on an example where this class was used in onActivityResult on the result.  So please do a little effort to find it.